# Alterar Imagem HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou começando a aprender HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT, e estou com um projeto de um site, vou tentar explicar o que eu quero. Eu tenho 3 imagens de espelhos quebrados e quero que ao clicar em cada imagem apareça a foto dentro do espelho, porém não estou conseguindo e quando eu clico na imagem ela troca apenas de um espelho.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>TE AMO</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="styles.css" />
     
  </head>
  <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(a) {
        document.getElementById("quadro1").src=a;
    }
</script>
</div>
      <div class="momentos-menu">
      <img src="imagens/momentos.png" class="momentos">
      <div id="quadro">
      <div class="row">
  <div class="coluna"> 
    <img id="quadro1" src="imagens/quadro.png" onclick='changeImage("imagens/quadro-foto-1.png");'>
  </div>
  <div class="coluna">
    <img id="quadro1" src="imagens/quadro.png" onclick='changeImage("imagens/quadro-foto-2.png");'>
  </div>
  <div class="coluna">
    <img id="quadro1" src="imagens/quadro.png" onclick='changeImage("imagens/quadro-foto-3.png");'>
    
  </div></div>
          </div>
      </div>
   

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma id tem que ser única numa página, por isso você está modificando o mesmo elemento. O jeito mais fácil de resolver o problema é entendendo que os event handlers em atributos têm acesso ao elemento como `this`.

```js
function changeImage(img, src) {
  img.src = src;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200" onclick="changeImage(this, 'https://picsum.photos/id/2/200')" />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200" onclick="changeImage(this, 'https://picsum.photos/id/3/200')" />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200" onclick="changeImage(this, 'https://picsum.photos/id/4/200')" />
```

Mas você deveria usar `addEventListener` e `data-` attributes e delegação de eventos para melhor separação entre HTML e Javascript e também conservando memória por precisar de um event handler ao invés de um por imagem.

```js
document.getElementById("quadro").addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   const target = event.target;
   if (target.matches("img")) {
     target.src = target.dataset.over;
   }
});
```

```html
<div id="quadro">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200" data-over="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200" data-over="https://picsum.photos/id/3/200">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200" data-over="https://picsum.photos/id/3/200">
</div>
```

Comment: Opá primeiramente obrigado pela resposta e ajuda, mas ao tentar utilizar o primeiro codigo não obtive sucesso e simplesmente ao clicar em qualquer quadro o primeiro sumia, e no segundo codigo não apareceu nenhum efeito visiviel.

Comment: @RianBittencourt Não sei o que você não conseguiu, mas eu criei um exemplo que você pode executar aqui mesmo